# Password-Recovery Email formulation is suboptimal

Tags: feature-request, account-recovery

So my co-worker recently wanted to access their account again, and had forgotten their password. They requested an account recovery and recieved an email. The formulation is IMO very unclear and should be fixed:

Following excerpt:

> You can [log in to Stack
>   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login)  using the following
>   credentials:
>
> - Choose the "Log in with Stack Exchange" option ([redacted]) ([reset your
>     password](https://stackoverflow.com/account/recover?recoveryToken=[redacted])
>     if you've forgotten it)

```
You can log in to Stack Overflow <https://stackoverflow.com/users/login>  using the following credentials:

*   Choose the "Log in with Stack Exchange" option ([redacted]) 
    (reset your password <https://stackoverflow.com/account/recover?recoveryToken=[redacted]>  
    if you've forgotten it)
```

This formulation is extremely unclear. I propose it to be changed to the following:

```
You can set a new password <[recovery-link]> and then log in using 
one of the following options on the login page <[login-page link]>:

*   "Log in with Stackexchange"
*   "Log in with Facebook"
*   "...."
```

> You can [set a new password](https://stackoverflow.com/account/recover) and then log in using one of the following options on the [login page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login):
>
> - "Log in with Stackexchange"
> - "Log in with Facebook"
> - "...."

Comment: Err, but resetting your password only makes sense if you're trying to log in with the Stack Exchange OpenID provider. If they're reminded they can log in using their previously linked Facebook/Google/whatever account they don't need to do that.

Comment: @TimStone that doesn't make this formulation less confusing, I'd say...

Comment: What specifically was unclear about it?

Comment: @AnnaLear My coworker expected to be provided with actual credentials (username, password) after the colon. The "reset password" option was not clear enough, since the first "order" was "log in here". My coworker went to the login-page link to get a new password / login and there (somwehat understandably) rerequested a new password, since no option to change the password was given :( The most important link of the mail was buried inside parens somewhere in a block with unexpected content.